# Difference between IOB Accuracy and Precision

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, precision, named-entity-recognition

I'm doing some works on NLTK with named entity recognition and chunkers. I retrained a classifier using `nltk/chunk/named_entity.py` for that and I got the following mesures:

```
ChunkParse score:
    IOB Accuracy:  96.5%
    Precision:     78.0%
    Recall:        91.9%
    F-Measure:     84.4%
```

But I don't understand what is the exact difference between IOB Accuracy and Precision in this case. Actually, I found on the docs ([here](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch07.html)) the following for an specific example:

> The IOB tag accuracy indicates that more than a third of the words are
>   tagged with O, i.e. not in an NP chunk. However, since our tagger did
>   not find any chunks, its precision, recall, and f-measure are all
>   zero.

So, if IOB accuracy is just the number of O labels, how come we don't have chunks and IOB accuracy is not 100% at the same time, in that example?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a very detailed explanation of the difference between precision and accuracy on wikipedia (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision), in brief:

```
accuracy = (tp + tn) / (tp + tn + fp + fn)
precision = tp / tp + fp
```

Back to NLTK, there is a module call [ChunkScore](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn-/trunk/doc/api/nltk.chunk.util-pysrc.html#ChunkScore) that computes the `accuracy`, `precision` and `recall` of your system. And here's the funny part the way NLTK calculates the `tp,fp,tn,fn` for `accuracy` and `precision`, it does at different granularity.

For **accuracy**, NLTK calculates the total number of tokens (**NOT CHUNKS!!**) that are guessed correctly with the POS tags and IOB tags, then divided by the total number of tokens in the gold sentence.

```
accuracy = num_tokens_correct / total_num_tokens_from_gold
```

For **precision** and **recall**, NLTK calculates the:

- `True Positives` by counting the number of chunks (**NOT TOKENS!!!**) that are guessed correctly
- `False Positives` by counting the number of chunks (**NOT TOKENS!!!**) that are guessed but they are wrong.
- `True Negatives` by counting the number of chunks (**NOT TOKENS!!!**) that are not guessed by the system.

And then calculates the precision and recall as such:

```
precision = tp / fp + tp
recall = tp / fn + tp
```

To prove the above points, try this script:

```
from nltk.chunk import *
from nltk.chunk.util import *
from nltk.chunk.regexp import *
from nltk import Tree
from nltk.tag import pos_tag

# Let's say we give it a rule that says anything with a [DT NN] is an NP
chunk_rule = ChunkRule("<DT>?<NN.*>", "DT+NN* or NN* chunk")
chunk_parser = RegexpChunkParser([chunk_rule], chunk_node='NP')

# Let's say our test sentence is:
# "The cat sat on the mat the big dog chewed."
gold = tagstr2tree("[ The/DT cat/NN ] sat/VBD on/IN [ the/DT mat/NN ] [ the/DT big/JJ dog/NN ] chewed/VBD ./.")

# We POS tag the sentence and then chunk with our rule-based chunker.
test = pos_tag('The cat sat on the mat the big dog chewed .'.split())
chunked = chunk_parser.parse(test)

# Then we calculate the score.
chunkscore = ChunkScore()
chunkscore.score(gold, chunked)
chunkscore._updateMeasures()

# Our rule-based chunker says these are chunks.
chunkscore.guessed()

# Total number of tokens from test sentence. i.e.
# The/DT , cat/NN , on/IN , sat/VBD, the/DT , mat/NN , 
# the/DT , big/JJ , dog/NN , chewed/VBD , ./.
total = chunkscore._tags_total
# Number of tokens that are guessed correctly, i.e.
# The/DT , cat/NN , on/IN , the/DT , mat/NN , chewed/VBD , ./.
correct = chunkscore._tags_correct
print "Is correct/total == accuracy ?", chunkscore.accuracy() == (correct/total)
print correct, '/', total, '=', chunkscore.accuracy()
print "##############"

print "Correct chunk(s):" # i.e. True Positive.
correct_chunks = set(chunkscore.correct()).intersection(set(chunkscore.guessed()))
##print correct_chunks
print "Number of correct chunks = tp = ", len(correct_chunks)
assert len(correct_chunks) == chunkscore._tp_num
print

print "Missed chunk(s):" # i.e. False Negative.
##print chunkscore.missed()
print "Number of missed chunks = fn = ", len(chunkscore.missed())
assert len(chunkscore.missed()) == chunkscore._fn_num
print 

print "Wrongly guessed chunk(s):" # i.e. False positive.
wrong_chunks = set(chunkscore.guessed()).difference(set(chunkscore.correct()))
##print wrong_chunks
print "Number of wrong chunks = fp =", len(wrong_chunks)
print chunkscore._fp_num
assert len(wrong_chunks) == chunkscore._fp_num
print 

print "Recall = ", "tp/fn+tp =", len(correct_chunks), '/', len(correct_chunks)+len(chunkscore.missed()),'=', chunkscore.recall()

print "Precision =", "tp/fp+tp =", len(correct_chunks), '/', len(correct_chunks)+len(wrong_chunks), '=', chunkscore.precision()
```

Comment: Thank you! It's much more clear now. I think this is a relevant information that should be present in the docs of NLTK because these numbers are the fastest and more direct way of evaluating a classifier trained with NLTK and if we want to use and present them we have to feel confortable with using them.

Comment: ah it's because NLTK's purpose was not really to do NLP but to demonstrate and teach NLP, so sometimes the tutor would assign the task of asking students "why is accuracy different from precision?" or "which score should you use to optimize the classifier?". I would suggest to look into the master code to verify some "peculiarities" of NLTK https://code.google.com/p/nltk/