# How to get the precision and recall from a nltk classifier?

Tags: python, python-2.7, nltk

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

documents = [(list(movie_reviews.words(fileid)), category)
             for category in movie_reviews.categories()
             for fileid in movie_reviews.fileids(category)]


all_words = []

for w in movie_reviews.words():
    all_words.append(w.lower())

all_words = nltk.FreqDist(all_words)

word_features = list(all_words.keys())[:3000]

def find_features(document):
    words = set(document)
    features = {}
    for w in word_features:
        features[w] = (w in words)

    return features

featuresets = [(find_features(rev), category) for (rev, category) in documents]

training_set = featuresets[500:1500]
testing_set = featuresets[:1500]

classifier = nltk.DecisionTreeClassifier.train(training_set)

print "Classifier accuracy percent:",(nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier, testing_set))*100 , "%"

string = raw_input("Enter the string: ")
print (classifier.classify(find_features(word_tokenize(string))))
```

This code will display the accuracy of the classifier and then get input from user. And it returns the polarity of the string input by the user.

But here's my question: since I can obtain the accuracy by using `nltk.accuracy()`, is it possible to get its precision and recall as well?

Comment: You are looking for the [`nltk.metrics.scores`](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.metrics.html#module-nltk.metrics.scores) module.

Comment: Although the functions are nicely coded, it's good to understand what's under the hood, esp. when it comes to evaluation, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17325554/iob-accuracy-on-nltk-named-entity-recognition

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're using the nltk package, then it appears you can use the `recall` and `precision` functions from `nltk.metrics.scores` ([see the docs](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.metrics.html)).

The functions should be available after invoking

```
from nltk.metrics.scores import (precision, recall)
```

Then you need to call them with `reference` (known labels) and `test` (the output of your classifier on the test set) sets.

Something like the code below should produce these sets as `refsets` and `testsets`

```
refsets = collections.defaultdict(set)
testsets = collections.defaultdict(set)

for i, (feats, label) in enumerate(testing_set):
    refsets[label].add(i)
    observed = classifier.classify(feats)
    testsets[observed].add(i)
```

Then, you can see the precision and recall for positive predictions with something like

```
print( 'Precision:', nltk.metrics.precision(refsets['pos'], testsets['pos']) )
print( 'Recall:', nltk.metrics.recall(refsets['pos'], testsets['pos']) )
# `'pos'` is for the "positive" (as opposed to "negative") label
```