# How to calculate recall, precision and f-measure?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nltk

I'm working on a sentiment analysis project and I'm beginner in Python. 
I need to calculate recall, precision and f-measure but I don't know the syntax for my data sets, which look like this:

```
#The train data format ,contains text's words with their weights and the text's class label

train_set = [
    ({'adam': 0.05,'is': 0.0, 'a': 0.0, 'good': 0.02, 'man': 0.0}, 1),
    ({'eve': 0.0, 'is':  0.0, 'a':  0.0,'good':  0.02,'woman': 0.0}, 1),
    ({'adam': 0.05, 'is': 0.0, 'evil': 0.0}, 0)]

#0 or 1 for class label

#Test data the same as train data
```

This is my current code

```
from nltk.classify import apply_features

def naivebyse(finaltfidfVector):
    train_set = []
    j = 0
    for vector in finaltfidfVector:
        if j < 2100: #take 70% of data for train
            train_set.append(vector)
            j += 1
        else:
            break

    test_set = []
    j = 0
    for vector in finaltfidfVector:
        if j < 3000 and j >= 2100: # 30% for test
            test_set.append(vector)
        if j>= 3000:
            break
        j += 1

    classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set)
    print("Accuracy of sarcasm classifier : ", 
     (nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier, test_set)*100))
    refsets = collections.defaultdict(set)
    testsets = collections.defaultdict(set)

    for i, (feats, label) in enumerate(test_set):
        refsets[label].add(i)
        observed = classifier.classify(feats)
        testsets[observed].add(i)

    print("Precision percentage : " , nltk.metrics.precision(refsets['1'], 
    testsets['1'])*100)
    print("Recall Percentage : ", nltk.metrics.recall(refsets['1'], 
    testsets['1'])*100)
```

Exception

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
unable to realloc 20234 bytes
```

Can anyone provide some hints on how to carry out the task?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to calculate those metrics on the training set. Where is the output of your system?

Comment: The output is what i need to calculate .

Comment: I need to know what i must do for these measures !

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have false data in the training set, so everything will be a True Positive, with True Negatives, False Negatives and False Positives all being set to 0. Then the formulas for precision and recall will give you 1. F-Measure will be 1 too.

Comment: [Formulas for precision and recall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall#Definition_(classification_context))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the precision and recall from a nltk classifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45466041/how-to-get-the-precision-and-recall-from-a-nltk-classifier)

Comment: @DavideFiocco what is cross_valid_set in the code of the link that you'r sent ?,i don't understand

Comment: @AsmaaAbd_El3al that's equivalent to your `test_set`. I have submitted an edit to make it clearer in that accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23281672 (as it stands it's a bit confusing, I agree)

Comment: nltk.metrics.precision(refsets['pos'], testsets['pos'] ,'pos' in my case is '1' right ?

Comment: @AsmaaAbd_El3al yes, i'd say so, try it out!

Comment: I have submitted an edit to my code .

Answer (score 1):

You could use the scikit-learn library to do so e.g. with

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, f1_score, precision_score, recall_score, classification_report, confusion_matrix

f1 = f1_score(y_test, y_pred)

prec = precision_score(y_test, y_pred)

recall = recall_score(y_test, y_pred) `
```

Not sure if that applies to your dataset, but it is a best practice to perform [cross validation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/statistical_inference/model_selection.html#model-selection-tut) as well.